# In App Engine Queues, what happens to existing tasks when queue.yaml changes?

Tags: google-app-engine, queue

I have a bunch of tasks running in the queue, the original queue.yaml file had a specific rerty limit. I would like to change that retry limit on the existing tasks that are waiting in the queue (we're talking days not hours). And I'm wondering if changing the values in the queue.yaml file will allow me to do this. If not, then I would appreciate an alternative. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, changing the retry limit for a queue in queue.yaml is applicable to the tasks already in that queue.  This means that when a task on the queue is selected for execution, if its retry limit has now already been reached (due to queue.yaml changes), it will be removed and not executed.  [This trick can be used to clear out problem tasks that are erroring and being retried multiple times - set the queue retry limit to a low value to clear out the queue of the problematic tasks, then raise the retry limit again].

If an individual task has a retry limit explicitly set, this will override the queue settings.